# How to select where field1 not like '%query2%'

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm creating a view and want to exclude the rows that have an timestamp containing today's date.
I'm thinking something like `where field not like '%date_format(curdate(), '%Y%m%d')%';` but not sure how to make this work as if I used it without a wildcard at least afterwards, then it would match all because the field doesn't equal just the date.

Example timestamp I'm dealing with: 20210219153933
I want to exclude ones that contain the current date in the format %Y%m%d

Thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Edit: my timestamp column is `char(16)`

Comment: Is the column a VARCHAR type rather than a DATETIME type? You could cast it to a DATETIME for the comparison with MySQL's date functions - comparing with a `LIKE` feels wrong, but if that is the approach you take you'd need to concatenate the wildcards onto the string `LIKE CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y%m%d'), '%')`

Comment: Note: if you are using wildcards, don't put one on the left so that you don't match the date _inside_ the string. You want it left-anchored.

Answer (score 0):

You could say

```
where field < 20210219000000
```

(assuming you have numeric date time values in your table).
This would just set teh time part to 0 (midnight) and keep the date part.

Comment: This would be good, but I need it to change given the date so that the view automatically adjusts, (I want to create a view the view the day's logs with other filters making a view the best option). The original table will always be there to give all available data

Comment: but your timestamps are integers like you showed in your question?

Comment: yeah, but I want the view to display the results for the particular day at hand, not a static date

Answer (score 0):

Answer was posted as a comment: CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y%m%d'), '%')